# Transfer files from laptop to Macbook Air

Tags: windows-xp, macbook, display, file-transfer

My Dell laptop's screen no longer works, and I need to transfer all the music and photos to my new Macbook Air. What is the best way to do this?

My old laptop is running on Windows XP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could connect the Dell to an external monitor, [share out the hard drive](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304040), [connect to it from the Mac](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1568) and copy over the files.

Alternatively you could get a [USB hard drive adapter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000HJ99DI) (about $20) and connect the drive directly to the Mac.

Another option to consider is to make a virtual machine from the Dell and run it on the Mac.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say pull out the hard drive on the Dell and place it in an enclosure to pull the files or hook the Dell to an external monitor and pull the files that way.